What I am missing after creating private rpc Solana node
I create rpc Solana on dedicate server from edgevana. I use my rpc endpoints in trade bot when I use heluis https and wss the bot run and start , when I use my https and wss the bot exit and get error message that my wallet run of sol . Some traders said this a problem in websocket . What I am missing ?
Https:domain.com:8899 wss:domain:8900
I know it is not a wallet issue
